# how to hit a rest webservice through ajax in java

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

here is the webservice url which gets results how to  hit that url which gives a result true or false

```
function uniqueness(){
    var xhr;
    //var contextpath=document.getElementById("contextpath").value.trim();
     var pub_name=document.getElementById('p_name').value.toLowerCase().trim();
     var pub_trimed_name=(pub_name).replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").replace("&", "")
        .replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "");
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
     else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      var url="http://125.63.88.114:8086/xchangeWebservice/resources/publisher/check_publisher/"+pub_trimed_name;
     // alert(url);
      xhr.open( 'POST',url, true );
      xhr.send(null);
      //xhr.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (response) {


       if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {
       var det = eval( "(" +  xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
               var size= det.size();

               if (det[0].book_title != "" ) {
                   alert("invalid ");
                }
        }
   };
}
```

here is the webservice url which gets results how to  hit that url which gives a result true or false

Comment: Please learn the difference between `Java` and `javascript`.

Comment: The code you have posted is for javascript. And what is the problem?